# How to log cookies from a cookie jar?

Tags: node.js, request-promise

How can I log cookies that are stored in a cookie jar using the request-promise npm module.

I have tried printing the cookie jar variable but as expected that does not work.

How I am creating the jar,

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var sess = request.jar()
```

The code sending the request,

```
request({url: myurl, jar: sess}, function () {
    request(
        {
            url: 'myurl',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: [
            {
                "Accept": "application/json",
            }
            ],
            postData: {
                "xqr":"1"
            }
        }
)
```

I expect all the cookies used to send my request to be printed out using `console.log()`

Comment: Your question is unclear. I can see two different requests there?

Comment: There is only one request? And I want to print the current cookies in sess.

Comment: I mean you need only the request cookies or all cookies in the jar (from different domains too)?

Comment: All the cookies from the jar yeah

Comment: I think OP stores some data like JWT or any authentication variable and wants to make the request with using this variable.

Comment: As you wanted all the cookies from the jar, I provided an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

[request](https://github.com/request/request) uses [tough-cookie](https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie) internally. So you can easily access to tough-cookie [store](https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie/blob/9ff4ba59eceab8f85f8104ac30d96cc0c9570d23/lib/store.js#L73) which is an abstract class and use its prototype function `getAllCookies`.

```
function logCookies(jar){
    jar._jar.store.getAllCookies(function(err, cookieArray) {
        if(err) throw new Error("Failed to get cookies");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cookieArray, null, 4));
    });
}
```

And this will log all cookies and its properties.

```
[
    {
        "key": "1P_JAR",
        "value": "1P_JAR_VALUE",
        "expires": "2019-01-23T20:09:38.000Z",
        "domain": "google.com",
        "path": "/",
        "hostOnly": false,
        "creation": "2018-12-24T20:09:37.800Z",
        "lastAccessed": "2018-12-24T20:09:38.097Z"
    },
    {
        "key": "NID",
        "value": "NID_VALUE",
        "expires": "2019-06-25T20:09:38.000Z",
        "domain": "google.com",
        "path": "/",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "hostOnly": false,
        "creation": "2018-12-24T20:09:37.802Z",
        "lastAccessed": "2018-12-24T20:09:38.098Z"
    }
]
```

If you only want to get raw cookie string you can just simply use

```
console.log(cookieArray.map(cookie => cookie.toString()))
```

And it will give you

```
[
    '1P_JAR=1P_JAR_VALUE; Expires=Wed, 23 Jan 2019 20:15:02 GMT; Domain=google.com; Path=/',
    'NID=NID_VALUE; Expires=Tue, 25 Jun 2019 20:15:02 GMT; Domain=google.com; Path=/; HttpOnly'
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out soon

Comment: I'm sort of confused as what cookieArray should be defined as? And when running the function nodejs is unable to get the value of jar_

Comment: It is the argument for getAllCookies method callback